# How to get JS file to animate code using GSAP?

Tags: javascript, gsap

I'm new to coding js, and am trying to use GSAP to animate some code. I cannot get anything to move or do any function. I don't have any errors when I compile my file. Also, I cannot get anything to animate on my CodePen, which I have been trying to use to see if I can try to do anything that might work. My html and css are working fine. I don't know what might be the problem?

CodePen:

https://codepen.io/ashleynw1800/pen/VwaRGBX

HTML:

```
<!-- Font Awesome-->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/3c79b583ac.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Google Fonts-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Abril+Fatface&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<section class="section-1">
    <div id="hello-container">
        <h1 class="hello"> hello!</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="happy-container">
        <i class="fa fa-smile-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
/* =============
    Demo
============= */

.section-1{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: ". hello happy .";
    grid-template-columns: "auto 2fr 1fr auto";
    background-color: #E6EBFF;
}

#hello-container{
    grid-area: hello;
    align-self: center;
}
.hello{
    font-size: 150px;
    font-family: 'Abril Fatface', cursive;
    color: #FF4F2D;
}

#happy-container{
    grid-area: happy;
    align-self: center;
    color: #FF89FF;
    font-size: 150px;
}
```

JS(I have taken all out except for one basic line to try to get anything to work):

```
import {gsap} from "gsap";

gsap.to(".hello", {duration:2, alpha:0})
```

Answer (score 1):

"Your mistake" ==> Wrong implementation of the module idea/concept:

> The module to import from. This is often a relative or absolute path
> name to the .js file containing the module.
> [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#:~:text=To%20dynamically%20import%20a%20module,js'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#:%7E:text=To%20dynamically%20import%20a%20module,js%27))%20.

Installation by `CDN` (Codepen). **Remove** `import {gsap} from "gsap";` and the code will work fine. Otherwise, you get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "gsap"

In general, it is very useful to inspect your code and check for console errors.
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console

**Related article:**

Failed to resolve module specifier
https://medium.com/@samichkhachkhi/failed-to-resolve-module-specifier-23fae20222df

#### Loading GSAP using modules tutorial:

https://greensock.com/docs/v3/Installation#npm